# Solr - Index informations merging from different data sources

Tags: solr, indexing

I have informations about the same documents (A,B,C) in 2 different places:

- A mysql DB that contains some fields (id, price, availability) about documents A,B,C
- Some xml files that contain other fields (id, reviews) about documents A,B,C

For the first source, I'd like to use DataImportHandler, for the second source I think I have to use the Update Xml Messages. Is this possible to do, merging informations that I have from different sources into one index? Is there some precautions to take? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by first importing the first source and later updating the documents based on id. Take into account [atomic updates](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates) which will definitely help you.